# Count number of values in dictionary object

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
<pre>
    products =     (
                {
            id = 19;
            "image_url" = "http://localhost:8888/straightoffer/image/data/1330374078photography.jpg";
            name = "Save $240 on your next photo session";
        },
                {
            id = 21;
            "image_url" = "http://localhost:8888/straightoffer/image/data/1330373696massage.jpg";
            name = "One Hour  Massage";
        }
    );
}
</pre>
```

the above is what I got through json, I need to assign the values to uitableviews:

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        NSLog(@"Number of rows: %d",[[products objectForKey:@"products"] count]);
        return [[products objectForKey:@"products"] count];
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }
        NSString *currentProductName;
        currentProductName = [productKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"product name : %@", currentProductName);
        [[cell textLabel] setText:currentProductName];

        return cell;
    }
```

it returns 0 number of rows, I am newbie to ios please help me how I will assign these values to uitableview.

Regards

Comment: I need more information. This code looks okay. It goes wrong in the data retrieval part of this story. Can you add the code of how you fill the `products` dictionary?

Comment: can u log the `products` and show us..? if the `products` itself is the array you can just its count right?

Comment: products = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]; this is how the products is populated,, and when i log the contents with in first pre tag in question is printed

Comment: check in `numberOfRowsInSection`, whether the `products` is having values or nil

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection return nil

Comment: when I log the products in viewDiDLoaded it print the full json array but in case of numberOfRowsInSection it prints null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that what you posted is not json. It should be

```
{
    "products":[
        {
            "id":19,
            "image_url":"http://localhost:8888/straightoffer/image/data/1330374078photography.jpg",
            "name":"Save $240 on your next photo session"
        },
        {
            "id":21,
            "image_url":"http://localhost:8888/straightoffer/image/data/1330373696massage.jpg",
            "name":"One Hour  Massage"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json files.

---

---

I have used the above json file and did the following:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *jsonPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *products = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

DLog(@"products: %i", [[products objectForKey:@"products"] count] );

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Result is: products: 2.

You should be able to reproduce this.

Comment: the actual json i produced is the same as you mentioned, i print here what ever is logged by ios. the json is valid i have checked with your provided url.

Comment: Yes please i need more help because my json format is correct.

Comment: I have point out that products with my original code is well populated in viewDidLoad method but when i call numberOfRowsInSection it return me 0, why is it behaving like this.

Comment: Have you added [self.tableView reloadData]; after the data is loaded?

Comment: on which method should i add this?

Comment: Like in my post. Just after you load the data, it should reload the tableview